# Laravel7 Join Syntax error or access violation

Tags: mysql, join, laravel-7

I am trying to write a query where I am joining a messages table and a users table so I can get all messages for a specific user and get the name of the user each message was from.

Here is my query

```
   $inboxrow = DB::table('inbox_messages')
        ->join('inbox_messages', 'inbox_messages.to_userid', '=', Auth::id())
        ->join('users', 'users.from_userid', '=', 'inbox_messages.from_userid')
        ->select('inbox_messages.*', 'users.name')
        ->get();
```

My issue is the above gives me an error (see below) and not sure how to re-write my query to get what I need. Which is everything from the inbox_messages table where the to_userid equals the logged in persons userid and then get the name of the person who sent the message from the users table where the value of the column inbox_messages.from_user = the value from the column users.id

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 
'inbox_messages' (SQL: select `inbox_messages`.*, `users`.`name` from `inbox_messages` 
inner join `inbox_messages` on `inbox_messages`.`to_userid` = `3` inner join `users` 
on `users`.`from_userid` = `inbox_messages`.`from_userid`)
```

Comment: You use `inbox_messages` two times with the same name. Please, use once or use with alias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try with the below solution. Where I change extra join to where clause.

```
$inboxrow = DB::table('inbox_messages')        
        ->join('users', 'users.from_userid', '=', 'inbox_messages.from_userid')
        ->select('inbox_messages.*', 'users.name')
        ->where('inbox_messages.to_userid', '=', Auth::id())
        ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks that worked i just had to change your users.from_userid to be users.id but that fixed it thank you.